# Unable to Add Trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have the following script which drops/ creates six triggers for a MySQL database; v5.5.52.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS gene_lcase_insert;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS morph_lcase_insert;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS genus_lcase_insert;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS species_lcase_insert;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS python_lcase_insert;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS python_extract_year_insert;

/* Enforce lower-case on INSERT into 'gene' table */

CREATE TRIGGER gene_lcase_insert BEFORE INSERT ON gene
FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.name = LOWER(NEW.name);

/* Enforce lower-case on INSERT into 'morph' table */

CREATE TRIGGER morph_lcase_insert BEFORE INSERT ON morph
FOR EACH ROW
      SET NEW.name = LOWER(NEW.name); 

/* Enforce lower-case in INSERT into 'genus' table */

CREATE TRIGGER genus_lcase_insert BEFORE INSERT ON genus
    FOR EACH ROW
     SET NEW.name = LOWER(NEW.name);

/* Enforce lower-case on INSERT into 'species' table */

CREATE TRIGGER species_lcase_insert BEFORE INSERT ON species
  FOR EACH ROW
      SET NEW.name = LOWER(NEW.name);

/* Enforce lower-case on INSERT into 'python' table */

CREATE TRIGGER python_lcase_insert BEFORE INSERT ON python
  FOR EACH ROW
      SET NEW.sold_to = LOWER(NEW.sold_to),
          NEW.feeding = LOWER(NEW.feeding);

/* Extract year from date_of_birth on INSERT if not NULL */

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER python_extract_year_insert BEFORE INSERT ON python
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
          IF NEW.date_of_birth IS NOT NULL
              THEN
                  SET NEW.sequence_year =  YEAR(NEW.date_of_birth);
          END IF;
  END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Upon executing the script, I receive the following error - when the final 'CREATE TRIGGER' statement is reached:

```
ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table'
```

I then perform the following check, to see if the *TRIGGER* exists:

```
mysql> select trigger_name from information_schema.triggers;
+----------------------+
| trigger_name         |
+----------------------+
| gene_lcase_insert    |
| genus_lcase_insert   |
| morph_lcase_insert   |
| python_lcase_insert  |
| species_lcase_insert |
+----------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

It appears that the final '*python_extract_year_insert*' trigger is not being created; sanity check:

```
mysql> drop trigger python_extract_year_insert;
ERROR 1360 (HY000): Trigger does not exist
```

I am uncertain as to why this is occurring. Thanks in advance.

**Note:**

I have tried implementing the final trigger (python_extract_year_insert) utilizing a separate file, to see if it was a processing issue of some kind - to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your question:

> ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support
>   'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table

For any given table you can only have one trigger per each event (insert/update/delete) AND per each time of execution of said event (after/before).

Comment: This is no longer the case in MySQL 5.7, just for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the last two triggers since they are both `BEFORE INSERT ON python`.

Do you really need to lowercase everything?  If your `COLLATION` for the columns is `..._ci`, then comparisons will match upper and lower case.